# how to distinguish between same view (e.g. a +/- toggle button) in expandable listview row and open corresponding group on selection?

Tags: android, tags, expandablelistview

I am using an ExpandableListView. Each group is populated from a custom view, which has a toggle type of button (+/-).

I am able to open the corresponding group on selection. However, the state of toggle is not correct when scrolled. I'm kind of confused on how to use the tags and all.

The code in getView is as follows:

```
if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.h_header_layout_exp_list, null);

        root.findViewById(R.id.call_icon).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operationExecutorFromExpList.launchDialer();
            }
        });

        view = root;
    }
    else{
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expander)).setTag(groupPosition);
        view = convertView;
    }

    final ImageView expandImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.expander);
    expandImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int imageId = isExpanded ? android.R.drawable.ic_input_add : R.drawable.ic_minus;
            expandImageView.setImageResource(imageId);
            operationExecutorFromExpList.animateGroup(isExpanded, groupPosition);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the image resource also outside the onclick listener for default UI rendering-

```
int imageId = isExpanded ? R.drawable.ic_minus : android.R.drawable.ic_input_add;
expandImageView.setImageResource(imageId);
```